# Any simple and lightweight tool to transform LaTex to MathML?

Tags: type-conversion, latex, converters, mathml

I need something that perform text-to-text transformation. Expected using is a server-side (passing LaTex and put back its MathML equivalent).

So, anyone has some advices for software to look forward at?

I've already tried latexml but that's hard to say it is a lightweight one and, moreover, it is slow and I faced with some unexpected bugs while did test transformings.

Also, I've tried pandoc but without success looks like i pass wrong params.

`echo '\frac{1}{3}' |pandoc -f latex -t html --mathml`

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227195/latex-to-mathml-conversion-tools-limitations-and-approaches